# SpellCheck in c#

Tags: c#

I am writing a c# code for spellchecking using Word.dll. I have used the following site as reference: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2469/SpellCheck-net-spell-checking-parsing-using-C

But i am getting an error: "The type or namespace name 'Word' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

The code that I am using is:

```
    SpellCheck word = new SpellCheck();

    bool status = false;
    string s = "youes";

    Console.WriteLine("Checking for word : " + s );

    // check to see if the word is not correct  
    // return the bool (true|false)
    status = word.CheckSpelling(s);

    if (status == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This word is misspelled : " + s);
        Console.WriteLine("Here are some suggestions");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");

        foreach( string suggestion in word.GetSpellingSuggestions(s) ) 
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine( suggestion ); 
        }
    }
    else if (status == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This word is correct : " + s );
    }
```

I just want to know how can I make it work?

Comment: `using Word;` is this on top of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class in your solution and call it Word.cs.
Open the “Browse Code” tab in [the article at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=2469), click Word.cs to view it's source code. Copy and paste it to your Word.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

You should download the source code. There is a file named Word.cs, and you should add that file to your project. Word namespace and SpellCheck class are defined in that file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add refernce to Micorsoft.Office.Interop.Word under .Net